# Optional quote in Informatica

Tags: string, informatica, informatica-powercenter

In Informatica, when we are reading a delimted file, we have an option in the File properties to treat quote(") as a possible data embedder. Can I customize this to quote followed by a comma(",) ?

Example :

Input : "Stack ,"OverFlow","Stack OverFlow"

Current Output : Stack ,,Stack OverFlow

Expected Output : Stack ,"OverFlow,Stack OverFlow

CodePage I'm currently using is 7-bit ASCII

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you need to use a different `Column Delimiter` instead of using `Optional Quotes` on `Source Definition`. Please try setting the `Column Delimiter` to `,"`. As a result you should get

`"Stack`, `OverFlow"`, `Stack OverFlow"`

Now you'd need to do some data cleansing and have the empty spaces [] and double quotes [`"`] removed.